# Why is IE9 replacing post method with get method in wicket form?

Tags: java, wicket

I have some button in my application:

```
private class MyForm extends Form<Parametry> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public MyForm(final Parametry parametry) {
        add(new AjaxButton("1") { .... }
        add(new AjaxButton("2") { .... }
        add(new Button("run") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                logger.error("???????????????????" + parametry.getDatum());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In Firefox and Chrome everything works but I have problem with IE8. Ajax button works fine but when I push the button nothing happens. Just the page is new (`?x` = `?x+1`) but `logger` doesn't write anything.

How I can fix it ?

---

**UPDATE:** I am using version 1.5.7. When I remove ajaxButton everything works.

---

**UPDATE2:** I used wireshark to see comunications:

Firefox:

> POST /rob-mon/statistika?5-4.IFormSubmitListener-statistikaForm
>   HTTP/1.1

This should be good.

IE9:

> GET
>   /rob-mon/statistika?4-1.IBehaviorListener.0-statistikaForm&random=0.2323892690702561
>   HTTP/1.1

Why is it using `GET` method?

Comment: try overriding onError() on the Button and see if get there.

Comment: nope still nothing. I also tried to add feedback panel to get some error but it doesnt help too.

Comment: Shouldn't the button be in a form to work?

Comment: yes there are in form ...  private class MyForm extends Form<Parameter>

Comment: @Hudi I see, fair enough. I would probably bring out [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) at this point to see what exactly is sent from the browser to the server.

Comment: Is the button with the name "run" marked as ```type="submit"``` in the markup? I have had issues with IE behaving unexpected if the attribute is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, can't you override `onSubmit` for your `Form` instead of for the button? You could even lose the button and keep a simple `<input type="submit" />` not tied to Wicket, which should work I think.

Comment: hm and what if I keep existing button and add the same onSubmit code to form on submit. Is this wrong ?

Comment: I would say it's needless duplication, but sure, you can.. Just be sure to handle in code that both `onSubmit` methods would be called sequentially.

Comment: hm I see then this button is submit twice in mozilla and chrome. is there some option to get browser ?

Comment: this is optimalization for IE9 so I dont want to delete this button from java code and replace it  in form method

Comment: It's not an _optimalization_, it's how you *should* be handling form submission. There's various ways in which forms can be submitted from various clients. Your code currently only handles just the specific case of having your button pressed. Overriding `Form#onSubmit` handles all cases including having that button pressed.

Comment: but there is still interesting that IE9 is using get method instead of post

Comment: Thanks, I agree that it's weird behaviour from IE9. I can't test it here as I'm on linux, but it could be worth reporting as a small self contained example to Wicket. In my opinion they should be the ones to make their framework handle browser implementation details such as this, where they affect form handling.

Comment: I am using linux too :) so this I bigger problem to me. I need to install wine and then IE

Answer (score 0):

Wicket AjaxButtons work by adding to an onclick event to the element. Do you have any js library which could be interfering with the onclick event handler wicket generates? I recall having some issue with a placeholder plugin.

Option 2: use `AjaxFallbackButton` ?